# selecting iterations in random and grid search

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, random-forest, hyperparameter

I am trying to optimizing a random forest for binary classification. 
I am tuning cutoff, ntrees, mtyr and maxnodes using MLR library in R. For searching these parameters i have to define a tuning method and one evaluation method.

For example defining tuning method.

```
## ex: random search with 100 iterations
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 100L)
```

My question, is there any thumb rule to define number of iterations for random or grid search or 100 is a standard value to be use.